# How to deploy react project with server adress and password

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, web-deployment

my company has provided data for deploying react project

VM Name: VM name

Instance Type: t3.micro (2CPU and 1GB RAM, 50GB SSD)

Public IP: 42.52.....

Username: username

Passowrd: password

they told me to deploy react project to this server

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auth_basic` method within nginx and or look to restrict via IP address if the company has a static IP using `allow` `deny` methods.

You can find good examples here:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/